# How to disable the Code Editor in Gutenberg?

Tags: block-editor

While there already are similar questions around this topic I have yet to find anything about disabling the Code editor in Gutenberg permanently, for all users:

[image: Code editor]

Using Gutenberg is a must, so I'm not looking for solutions regarding the classic editor or alternative editor plugins.

A code snippet that disables the editor would be much welcomed (I don't want to use a UI-only option). If this can't be achieved through hooks in the backend, I would also accept solutions that only affect the front end (since the backend receives HTML regardless of the editor used). Using `display: none` to hide the option would be one way to do it but I'd prefer a more permanent solution.

The main reason for this is for security. I have already disabled many blocks and the patterns.

I have already tried returning `false` on `wp_code_editor_settings` but that did not do anything to the Gutenberg editor.

Comment: Looking at the source code. There doesn't appear to be a way to do this. Hiding the option with CSS is the best you're going to do, but that won't stop the keyboard shortcut from working, so you'd just be making it hard to fix the issue if the user switched accidentally.

Comment: I'm curious what security issues you think you're solving by doing this though?

Comment: @JacobPeattie The idea is that the user could insert custom HTML into the code editor which I want to prevent. While it might not prevent someone from doing it in other means, it would greatly reduce support requests when they think they know what they're doing but in reality they don't. It might break certain pages or not have desired behavior and that is to be avoided. The other reason is that corporate cyber security asks to mitigate this which means, even if it is not reasonable to disable, they're still expecting mitigation.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Unfortunately you’re out of luck, as this doesn’t seem to be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the code editor by hooking into the `block_editor_settings_all` filter:

```php
add_filter(
    'block_editor_settings_all',
    static function (array $settings): array {
        $settings['codeEditingEnabled'] = false;
        return $settings;
    }
);
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/editor-filters/#codeeditingenabled) for more options.